# Store all previous strings from column as list in cell of new column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (10M+ rows) in long format, where each row consists of a hospital visit and a corresponding diagnosis, with several visits possible for any patient.

I would like to create a new column, that summarizes all ***previously awarded unique*** diagnoses for that patient.

It's straightforward to create a new column containing a list summarizing all diagnoses awarded anytime, but this doesn't do it for me.

```
What I tried so far:


df.groupby( ["Patient_ID"] )["Diagnosis"].unique().to_frame(name = "all_diagnoses").reset_index()

Patient_ID  all_diagnoses
2           [R104]
3           [O820, K429]
4           [R319, R339, N409, C619]
5           [J189, K578]
10          [C619, S202, R410]


Desired output:

Visit_ID  Patient_ID    ARRIVAL          Diagnosis      Newcol
52591     2             2/1/12 14:30     R104           [R104]
78131     3             4/26/12 7:00     O820           [O820]
78132     3             3/7/13 8:00      K429           [O820, K429]
61204     4             1/4/13 0:05      R319           [R319]
61202     4             1/10/13 15:00    R339           [R319, R339]
61205     4             4/23/13 10:00    N409           [R319, R339, N409]
61203     4             5/9/13 10:30     R319           [R319, R339, N409]
61206     4             5/30/13 3:40     C619           [R319, R339, N409, C619]
54263     5             3/28/12 23:10    J189           [J189]
54262     5             4/7/12 23:55     K578           [J189, K578]
111804    10            1/10/11 9:00     C619           [C619]
111803    10            5/16/12 20:00    S202           [C619, S202]
111805    10            7/18/12 14:30    R410           [C619, S202, R410]
82785     10            5/17/13 17:50    R410           [C619, S202, R410]
68737     10            11/28/13 10:30   R410           [C619, S202, R410]




This is not what I want:

Visit_ID  Patient_ID    ARRIVAL          Diagnosis      Newcol
52591     2             2/1/12 14:30     R104           [R104]
78131     3             4/26/12 7:00     O820           [O820, K429]
78132     3             3/7/13 8:00      K429           [O820, K429]
61204     4             1/4/13 0:05      R319           [R319, R339, N409, C619]
61202     4             1/10/13 15:00    R339           [R319, R339, N409, C619]
61205     4             4/23/13 10:00    N409           [R319, R339, N409, C619]
61203     4             5/9/13 10:30     R319           [R319, R339, N409, C619]
61206     4             5/30/13 3:40     C619           [R319, R339, N409, C619]
54263     5             3/28/12 23:10    J189           [J189, K578]
54262     5             4/7/12 23:55     K578           [J189, K578]
111804    10            1/10/11 9:00     C619           [C619, S202, R410]
111803    10            5/16/12 20:00    S202           [C619, S202, R410]
111805    10            7/18/12 14:30    R410           [C619, S202, R410]
82785     10            5/17/13 17:50    R410           [C619, S202, R410]
68737     10            11/28/13 10:30   R410           [C619, S202, R410]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
df2 =df.groupby('Patient_ID')['Diagnosis'].unique().to_frame()
df.merge(df2, how = 'left', left_on = 'Patient_ID', right_index = True )
```

### Explanation

We do the groupby and then turn the series in a dataframe.

```
df2 =df.groupby('Patient_ID')['Diagnosis'].unique().to_frame()
```

We then merge the original dataframe with this new dataframe;

```
 df.merge(df2, how = 'left', left_on = 'Patient_ID', right_index = True )
```

`how = left` means we are going to rely on the keys of the left dataframe (which will be the 'Patient_ID' of the left dataframe). Remember we adding to the orginal dataframe so we want this dataframe(left) to be the reference point.

`left_on` is the column which we want to use as the index keys from the left dataframe for the merge

`right_index` because we are using the index of the right dataframe (the grouped by dataframe)

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. The code you posted runs, but only gives the unique values of Diagnosis for each **Visit_ID**. I would want to collect all unique values of Diagnosis encountered for each **Patient_ID**, encountered up until the current Visit_ID in a list, and store that list in a new column in my original data frame.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I mistakenly interchanged the `Visit_ID` with the `Patient_ID`, I will switch them.

Comment: Let me know if it works ow. I think it should work now.

Comment: Thanks again, but it still doesn't work. The output generated by your code (after you changed it) records all diagnoses for each Patient_ID in the new column (see my edit above under "this is not what I want"). What I need is to store all diagnoses for each Patient_ID up until (and including) the present Visit_ID **but no future diagnoses**.

Comment: Ah! I see what you want! Someone with more expertise will probably be able to do it a lot quicker than I can. I will work it later if not.